# Devise using a previously existent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise, rails-routing

I'm working in a RoR 4.2.6 web application and I already had a model Contact when I decided to use Devise gem for authentication.

I installed devise 'by the book' and it is working fine, but... my other routes related to model Contact are all crazy. Let me explain it better.

My application requires that companies are able to register new contacts giving only first_name, surname, email and phones. These contacts will later log in and create a password for future access. Besides, a contact may register himself/herself the usual way, clicking at Devise 'create user' at the login form exhibited when there is not logged contact. As I said before, this works fine.

But when I clink the link "New contact" (pointing to contact/new as it should be) I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /contacts/sign_out
Couldn't find Contact with 'id'=sign_out"
```

and the trace (by better_errors gem) shows me this is happening at

```
private

def set_contact
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
end
```

This indicates to me that Devise is calling a method that requires to set the contact by its :id, but as the route is **contacts/sigh_out** it is passing **sign_out** as a parameter and this is causing the error. The, due to the 'routes created first are piority' rule I wrote

```
resources :contacts
```

before

```
devise_for :contacts
```

in my **config/routes.rb**, expecting that this would make the route to **contacts/new** be priority in relation to

```
destroy_contact_session DELETE /contacts/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

which is the route called to sign out with Devise. Didn't work, because this requires the user to be logged and it sends me back to Devise gem where I'm redirected to **contacts/sign_out** again, causing the same error.

Has someone faced a similar issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for editing, @teresko!

Comment: I expect that there's a before filter before_action :set_contact in your contact_controller.rb.
When you click on the New contact, it currently does not redirect you to devise_sessions_controller.rb#destroy.
Could you give us the result of `rake routes | grep contact` and the link_url of your New contact (retrieve it in the DOM)?

Comment: Yes, there is a before_action: :set_contact. But there is also a clause only: telling to go to :set_contact only for certain actions. The problem is the fact it is going to :set_contact when calling all devise methods.

Comment: I'll post the things you asked for as soon as I arrive in my desk, @Naremy. I'm at home and this project is not mine, but of the company I work for.